# AFNetworking 2.0 in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager how to pass HTTPBody tag

Tags: json, xcode, ios7, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.0, in this I have to pass json object in body part, How to pass HTTP Body in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'd suggest `appendWithFormData:name:`. Theoretically, if you felt compelled to specify the `Content-Type`, too, you could use `appendPartWithHeaders:body:`, manually specifying the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` headers, but it seems more cumbersome and probably unnecessary.

Comment: Where i need to add this method in above methods ?

Comment: Inside the `constructingBodyWithBlock` block. Right before or after your `appendPartWithFileURL`.

Comment: I have tried like this  [formData appendWithFormData - but there is no methods appendWithFormData, I need to pass HTTPBody

Comment: I want to like this NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

Answer (score 0):

Chatting with you offline, it sounds like the main concern is how to send profile image, name, email address, userid, and password in single request. It might look like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSURL *filePath = ...
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/registration.json" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"name"];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[email dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"email"];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[userid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"userid"];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"password"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

No JSON is needed.

If you wanted to use JSON, you can do that, but you wouldn't use the `constructingBodyWithBlock` method (which creates a `multipart/form-data` request). Instead, you'd just create a plain old JSON request, e.g.:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{
    @"name"     : name,
    @"email"    : email,
    @"userid"   : userid,
    @"password" : password,
    @"image"    : base64EncodedImage
};

[manager POST:@"http://example.com/registration.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Clearly, these are very different approaches, so whatever approach you adopt requires that the server code be written to handle the same API.